What to migrate to from native Xamarin?
I'm really new to .NET and Xamarin and I need to migrate an app that was written (not by me) for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android to something that's still supported. Right now there's a Visual Studio solution with a project for shared classes, and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects for platform specific code. It's a native Xamarin project but a lot of classes still have using Xamarin.Forms. I don't even know what I'm supposed to upgrade to, apparently .NET for android and .NET for iOS is what you're supposed to migrate to from native Xamarin, but also Maui is what you're supposed to migrate to if you're using Xamarin.Forms, but also Maui is hard to migrate to from native Xamarin? Does anyone know what I'm supposed to migrate to and how to do that?
I tried making a .NET for iOS project and just copy everything, but there's a lot of errors because of Xamarin.Forms and other dependencies

If you have Xamarin forms dependencies than the project you worked on was in Xamarin Forms which means you need to migrate to .NET MAUI

Refer to this, it should be a good starting point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-single-project?view=net-maui-8.0

Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.Forms have all been retired and are no longer updated, so you need to migrate your app to MAUI.
For details, you can refer to Xamarin.Android project migration and Xamarin.iOS project migration.

First confirm your current project is Xamarin Forms or Xamarin Native.
Xamarin Forms project has shared UI (xaml files) as well as logic and some platform specific code in Xamarin.ios and Xamarin.Android projects.
Xamarin Native project has shared logic and Native UI implementation (Storyboards/Xcode for Xamarin.ios & xml/axml files for xamarin.Android)
If it is Xamarin Forms project, Migrate to .Net MAUI Migrate Xamarin Forms
If it is Xamarin Native Project, consider migrating to .Net for Android/.Net for iOS respectively.Migrate Xamarin Native Projects
